# Type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | WebGLRenderingContext' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 Community with Typescript 1.5 Beta. I am getting the following error.

> Type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | WebGLRenderingContext' is not
>   assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

This is happening on the following line

```
var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = $(element).find('canvas').get(0);
var ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

I have set TypeScript tools version to both 1.4 and 1.5 and get the same error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the error message, the return type of `getContext` appears to be a union type, which means it is either one of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` or `WebGLRenderingContext`.

The compiler cannot tell which, so you need to help it out:

```
var ctx = <CanvasRenderingContext2D> canvas.getContext("2d");
```

However, if I try this with the latest version of everything, this works just fine:

```
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> $('#example').find('canvas').get(0);
var ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

So it looks like something isn't quite right.

The current definition of `getContext` has a specialized signature for the value "2d" that should give you back a `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. Here are the three signatures...

1. "2d" : `CanvasRenderingContext2D`
2. "experimental-webgl" : `WebGLRenderingContext`
3. other `string` : `CanvasRenderingContext2D | WebGLRenderingContext`

It should only give you back the union type if it doesn't recognise the string being passed in.

If your auto-completion doesn't suggest these three overloads when you type the `(` after `getContext`, that may indicate a problem.

[image: Auto-Completion for getContext with 2d argument]