# Canvas2D Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I am using Angular 11. I get this error and my page does not load.

[image]

As per the message I added willReadFrequently: true

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeUntil, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signature',
  templateUrl: './signature.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signature.component.css']
})
export class SignatureComponent {

  @ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef;

  @Input() public width = 250;
  @Input() public height = 75;

  private cx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });

    canvasEl.width = this.width;
    canvasEl.height = this.height;
```

But when I do ng build I get the following error

```
Error: app/shared-module/signature/signature.component.ts:21:5 - error TS2322: Type 'RenderingContext' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
  Type 'ImageBitmapRenderingContext' is missing the following properties from type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': globalAlpha, globalCompositeOperation, drawImage, beginPath, and 57 more.

21     this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
```

any clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | WebGLRenderingContext' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115328/type-canvasrenderingcontext2d-webglrenderingcontext-is-not-assignable-to-typ)

Comment: no, it does not.

Comment: Why not? It's exactly the same problem and has a solution.